# why my XFS file system got corrupted? root cause analysis

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

I have a block SAN storage volume mounted to my server via FC, I have formatted the volume with XFS.

I started experiencing file system corruption that can be easily repaired with xfs_repair, however I'm unable determine the root cause of the issue.

I'm positive it has nothing to do with my FC storage as other connected servers are operating normally.

Is there is logs / package I need to use to determine the root cause of such issue?

Environment RHEL 6.7

Thanks

Comment: *I'm positive it has nothing to do with my FC storage*  Don't be.  Are any of those other servers successfully running XFS file systems?  XFS is implemented in such a way that improper implementation of file system barriers anywhere between the running application and the data on disk can lead to corruption.  See https://lwn.net/Articles/283161/  ext2/3/4 aren't vulnerable to this because of the way they store data on disk.